# How to use cgroup limit in systemd user slices?

Tags: centos, systemd, cgroups

I have a CentOS 7.4 system which has a number of users who access the system via SSH.  I need a way to prevent them from consuming all CPU and memory of the system.  For example, each user getting 1 CPU core or a "1/20th share" of CPU time is fine.

The closest I have is based on setting the CPUQuota property of each user slice after a user logs in.  I did this but the settings have no effect.  What am I missing?

- `/etc/systemd/user.conf` had `DefaultCPUAccounting=yes` set then rebooted
- Logged in as test user
- `systemctl set-property user-43045.slice CPUAccounting=yes CPUQuota=20%`
- As the user, in a shell within the cgroup (systemd-cgls): `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null bs=1024k`

Still no limit to CPU usage.  Is there any *supported, not deprecated* way to limit SSH users?  Both the cgconfig+cgred method and the PAM method do not appear to work at all on CentOS 7.

#### EDIT #1 - and solution

After making the same change to `/etc/systemd/system.conf` the `CPUQuota` option now has an effect.  So systemd requires tracking things in both system and user for some reason.

Comment: Per the OP:  ... After making the same change to `/etc/systemd/system.conf` the `CPUQuota` option now has an effect. So systemd requires tracking things in both system and user for some reason.